# Добавление класса блоку в зависимости от наличия класса в другом блоке

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть такая html разметка:

```
<div id="header"></div>
<div id="carousel">
<div id="1">1</div>
<div id="2">2</div>
<div id="3">3</div>
</div>
```

В блоке carousel - слайдер (например, slick). Он листается автоматически, соответственно у блоков 1, 2 и 3 появляется/исчезает класс "active". При загрузке страницы класс "active" у блока 1 всегда по умолчанию.
Мне нужно, чтобы при принятии каждым из слайдов активного класса к блоку header добавлялся определённый класс.
Например:

блок 1 имеет класс "active" - header имеет класс "header-blue"

блок 2 имеет класс "active" - header имеет класс "header-red"

блок 3 имеет класс "active" - header имеет класс "header-green"

В js я не силён, смог наваять только такое:

```
if ($("#1").hasClass("active") ) {
$("#header").toggleClass("header-blue");
}
if ($("#2").hasClass("active") ) {
$("#header").toggleClass("header-red");
}
if ($("#3").hasClass("active") ) {
$("#header").toggleClass("header-green");
}
```

При загрузке страницы оно работает, далее конечно нет.
Прошу помощи у сообщества.

Comment: опубликуйте код который листает слайдер.

Comment: Там сайчас не slick, а slider pro.
`<div id="carousel" class="slider-pro">
<div class="sp-slides">
<div id="1" class="sp-slide">1</div>
<div id="2" class="sp-slide">2</div>
<div id="3" class="sp-slide">3</div>
</div>
<div class="sp-thumbnails">
<div class="sp-thumbnail">first</div>
<div class="sp-thumbnail">second</div>
<div class="sp-thumbnail">third</div>
</div>
</div>`

Answer (score 0):

Замените скрипт который листает слайды на этот

```
headerClasses = new Array("header-blue","header-red","header-green"); //массив с классами
function nextSlide(Case, header, index){
  $(Case).children('div').removeClass('active');
  var el = $(Case).children('div:eq('+index+')');
  $(el).addClass('active');
  var newClass = headerClasses[index];
  $(header).removeClass()
  $(header).addClass(newClass);
  index++;
  if(index >= headerClasses.length) index = 0;
  setTimeout(nextSlide, interval, Case, header, index);
}

interval = 2000;//интервал с которым листаются слайды в милисекундах
var Case = $('#carousel');//родительский элемент слайдов
var header = $('#header');
var index = 0;
nextSlide(Case, header, index);
```

или вот демонстрация работы кода https://jsfiddle.net/2jkLhavz/

Comment: Спасибо, но мне нужно использовать именно скрипт какого-нибудь из слайдеров. Мне нужны блоки sp-thumbnail для переключения слайдов sp-slide. То есть такая структура, как примерно сейчас по указанной ссылке. И со срабатыванием кликов по переключателям sp-thumbnail.